# Interface Name Class Method Selector

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm a real noob to objective C but I CANNOT figure out how to push transition from one view to another on a button click.

What I'm doing wrong here? I've #imported my Page2.h file in the header

I get these two errors

1 "unexpected interface name 'Page2': expected expression"

2 "No known Class method for selector 'setFrame'

```
- (IBAction)Page2Switcher:(id)sender {

    CGRect inFrame = [_Page1 frame];
    CGRect outFrame = Page2;
    outFrame.origin.x -= inFrame.size.width;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];

    [Page2 setFrame:inFrame];
    [_Page1 setFrame:outFrame];

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Comment: I get the Errors after I've declared "Page2"

Comment: You might want to check out the UIView reference page.  "Use of the methods in this section is discouraged in iOS 4 and later. Use the block-based animation methods instead."  Not to mention that the usage of blocks is much cleaner and easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a glaring inconsistency:

1. From the line: `CGRect outFrame = Page2;` you must have that `Page2` is of type `CGRect`, but this probably is not the case. Figure out what type `Page2` is and how to get a `CGRect` from it. Most likely, `Page2` is a `UIView` and you want to call `[Page2 frame]` instead.
2. From the line: `[Page2 setFrame:inFrame];`, you must have that `Page2` is some object that has a `frame` property, e.g. a subclass of `UIView`. This is inconsistent with 1 above where `Page2` is of type `CGRect`.

Comment: Page2 is probably the class of the view he is trying to show (since the file is named `Page2.h`)

Comment: Page 2 is a UIView that I'm trying to switch with another UIView called Page 1